# Error using Timer class, need simple way to make a countdown timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, compiler-errors

I used the java 7 class documentation exactly as it is written [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). Am I doing something wrong? I am trying to write a timer to count down from 10 to 0 and display the timer numbers as it counts down. My intelliJ tells me that when I create a new Timer class and pass in the constructors for delay and taskPreformer that

> Timer java.lang.String, boolean in timer cannot be applied to int java.awt.event.ActiveListener.

```
    int delay = 1000; // milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        int count = 10;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (count > 0) {
                count--;
            }
        }
    };

    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have imported the wrong `Timer`. There's a `java.util.Timer` with arguments `(String, boolean)` which is not the `Timer` you want. The timer you want is the `javax.swing.Timer`, which *does* have the arguments `(int, ActionListener)`. So fix the imports

```
//import java.util.Timer;  <-- take out
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Also, you may want some stopping condition for the timer to stop. Maybe something like

```
if (count > 0) {
    count--;
} else {
    ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
}
```